# How to create index on column to increase execution of query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I will not add query here because there is nothing special in query.
In query I have left join on 10 tables.

```
...left join tableB b on a.UserId = b.UserId
left join tableC c on a.UserId = c.UserId
left join tableD d on a.UserId = d.UserId
```

Execution of this query is **23 seconds**. That is already too much.
All tables are connected by `UserId` foreign key which is of type `uniqueidentifier`.
Now I thought that I maybe need to add indexes but I do this for the first time and I'am not sure am I doing it right.
In management studio I go to `table design > manage keys indexes > add index > in dropdown I select UserId (ASC)`
I do this in all 10 tables and after I run query execution of the query was **45 seconds**. And this is worse than before.
Am I doing something wrong in adding index?

Comment: Please post the execution plans before and after the change.

Comment: I added query to question. I never do with execution plans. What should I show you? I run it but I got very big text.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an index on User id will not help you if you are selecting any other column than User id. For maximum performance you could create an un-clustered index on each table that is ordered by the user id and also contains all of the other columns that you need for your query.

That would give you the best performance but there is a lot of overhead maintaining all of these indexes so you'll have to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

It was group by issue. I organize group by a little different and execution time is in miliseconds now :) Here what I did. I removed `count()` from select and whole group by section and in from I write:

```
select S3.TotalCheckIns
...
left join (select userid, count(CheckInId) as TotalCheckIns
   FROM dbo.checkins
   GROUP BY UserId) S3 on p.UserId = S2.UserId
   where p.UserId = @m_UserId
```

I have used technique from this link http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2005/12/14/8546.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the  Idea is create index for each FK and PK (this one is created automatically) doing that, your joins will speed up